# Make li horizontal change to vertical when browser gets smaller

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a `<ul>` list, all `<li>` items are displayed horizontal. What I want to do is make the last two `<li>` items stack vertically when the browser gets too small for them all to remain horizontal, instead of dropping to the next line.

I have created a jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xss5Q/)

So as you can see all the items align horizontally, but as you narrow the display window, instead of items 5 and 6 dropping to the next line I want then to stack horizontally and stay on the same line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align property` in your `<ul>` it may help you.

use Like this:

```
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/touchwithran/bnxPu/)

Answer (score 1):

```
text-align: right;
```

Add this to the containing `<ul>`, that should do the trick.